# Calling a controller action from a rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following in the application controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  def api_auth
    @api_key = Rails.application.secrets.api_key
    @api_secret = Rails.application.secrets.api_secret
    @host_id = Rails.application.secrets.host_id
    @data_type = 'JSON'

    @options = {
      body: {
        api_key: @api_key,
        api_secret: @api_secret,
        host_id: @host_id,
        data_type: @data_type
      }
    }
  end
end
```

In my controller I have...

```
  before_action :api_auth
  ...
  def get_stuff
response = HTTParty.post("api_url", @options)

stuffs = response.parsed_response["stuffs"]
current_stuffs = stuff.all
stuffs.each do |w|
  #unless stuff id already exists in DB, then create it
  #what about if an attribute of a stuff is updated? How do we capture that? UUID?
  unless (current_stuffs.pluck :stuff_id).map(&:to_s).include?(w["id"].to_s)
     stuff.create(stuff_id: w["id"], topic: w["topic"], start_time: w["start_time"], join_url: w["join_url"])
  end
end
```

end

..and the following rake task...

```
desc "Heroku task to get stuff"
task :get_stuff => :environment do
  puts "Getting stuff from api..."
  session = ActionDispatch::Integration::Session.new(Rails.application)
  session.post "/posts/get_stuff"
  puts "done."
end
```

The routes is correct, and I do not get any errors when running the task. However when I run the task my DB update action is not taking place.

I know the action works because I have a simple button_to set up in the view that calls the same action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're approaching it from the wrong end. Instead of trying to hit http endpoint from within the app, just perform the logic from that action directly.

You are in the app environment already and have access to all of the code! You don't *need* the http interface.

If you insist on using http interface, though, you can do this the same way you'd get an external api endpoint. Using [Net::HTTP](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html), for example.

Comment: I guess that is my question; how do I call the logic that is already there...in the controller. I get that the logic is in the code...the controller in this case. I could move the logic to the model and call it from there via a class method, but I think leaving the logic in the controller is a better fit for what I am wanting to do. Is there another way to call a controller other ran via a restful route?

Comment: @Lumbee Depends on what kind of logic it is. It is likely that it's better to move that logic elsewhere (model or service object or something like that)

Comment: I hear ya. I add a little more context and code in the question. Hopefully it makes more sense now.

Comment: @Lumbee: yeah, that's what I'm talking about. That kind of logic definitely does not belong in a controller. It should be extracted into a dedicated object, which queries that api. Controllers should be worrying about authenticating incoming users, rendering correct views, etc. Authenticating against an external api and knowing how to fetch data from it is not controller's business. Let alone knowing how to parse the response and what to do with it.

Answer (score 2):

For posterity here is what I came up with:

I got rid of the code in the app controller.

In stuff.rb I did...

```
class Stuff < ApplicationRecord

  def self.get_stuff       
    options = {
  body: {
    api_key: Rails.application.secrets.zoom_api_key,
    api_secret: Rails.application.secrets.zoom_api_secret,
    host_id: Rails.application.secrets.zoom_host_id,
    data_type: 'JSON'
  }
}
  end

  response = HTTParty.post("api_url", @options)

  stuffs = response.parsed_response["stuffs"]
  current_stuffs = stuff.all
  stuffs.each do |w|

    unless (current_stuffs.pluck :stuff_id).map(&:to_s).include?(w["id"].to_s)
     stuff.create(stuff_id: w["id"], topic: w["topic"], start_time: w["start_time"], join_url: w["join_url"])
  end
end
```

end

In the controller, just call the get get_stuff method with...

```
def get_stuff
    Stuff.get_stuff
end
```

..and the following rake task...

```
desc "Heroku task to get stuff"
task :get_stuff => :environment do
  puts "Getting stuff from api..."
  Stuff.get_stuff
  puts "done."
end
```